# Lightning Buddy Component Error: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, user-profile

I am a standard user and trying to navigate from one tab to another tab. Whenever I am going to account or opportunity tab I am seeing below error message. I tried to check if there is something wrong in debug but nothing is there in debug logs. Whenever I am navigating to this tab using system admin user there is no error.

[image]

Comment: are you using [LightningBuddy](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FKArSUAX) AppExchange product?

Comment: @sanketkumar Yeah, LightningBuddy is installed in system by someone else. Do I need to give any permission to the user to resolve this issue?

Comment: Others are having problems too - see the reviews section of the link Sanket posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the issue by giving CRED permission to the profile to below objects:

1. Actions
2. Carousel Image
3. Action User Preference
4. Toaster Alert Param
5. Record Criteria
6. Welcome Mat Tile

Note: You can find all the objects for LightningBuddy app from below path:
Setup -> Installed Packages -> Lightning Buddy -> View Components

Comment: Please accept this answer if it resolved your issue.